# Ellipse inscribed on a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, intuition, conic-sections

The problem is:

> Given that an ellipse is inscribed on a convex quadrilateral and each
>   one of it's diagonals pass through one foci of the ellipse show that
>   the product of the opposite sides are equal.

Now I've been thinking about this one for a while and I could transform this in an angle problem, please if someone can show that the two marked angles on the pic are equal I will appreciate (A and B are the focis of the ellipse $EHLG$ is the quadrilateral):

[image]

If at the end of this 6 days nobody comes with a plane geometry answer I'll reward the trigonometric solution

Comment: Am I allowed to post a shorter answer?

Comment: sure you are, if it is trigonometric though you will still need to wait a little more to get the 50 points

Answer (score 3):

This is a complete proof, and it might get a bit repetitive because I'm using the [Sine Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) again and again. I'm trying to find something more elegant, but this is the only thing thing I could come up with right now.( I've used a different diagram because my internet wasn't working while I was working this out. Just skip over to the ending note if you just want to see how the angles are equal.)

[image]

$DEGF$ is the quadrilateral and $A$ and $B$ are the foci.

Using sine law in $\Delta DBE$ you get $\dfrac{DE}{BE}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DBE}{\sin\angle BDE}$ and in $\Delta GBE$ you get $\dfrac{GE}{BE}=\dfrac{\sin\angle GBE}{\sin\angle BGE}$. Dividing the two you'll obtain: $\dfrac{DE}{GE}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DBE}{\sin\angle BDE}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\angle BGE}{\sin\angle GBE}\tag{i}$

Using sine law in $\Delta BDF$ you get $\dfrac{FD}{FB}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DBF}{\sin\angle BDF}$ and in $\Delta BGF$ you get $\dfrac{FG}{FB}=\dfrac{\sin\angle GBF}{\sin\angle BGF}$. Dividing the two you'll obtain: $\dfrac{FD}{FG}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DBF}{\sin\angle BDF}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\angle BGF}{\sin\angle GBF}\tag{ii}$

Dividing (i) and (ii):$\dfrac{DE\cdot FG}{GE\cdot FD}=\dfrac{\sin\angle BGE}{\sin\angle BDE}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\angle BDF}{\sin\angle BGF}\tag{iii}$

Using sine law in $\Delta DFI$ you get $\dfrac{DI}{FI}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DFE}{\sin\angle FDG}$ and in $\Delta GFI$ you get $\dfrac{GI}{FI}=\dfrac{\sin\angle GFE}{\sin\angle FGD}$. Dividing the two you'll obtain: $\dfrac{DI}{GI}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DFE}{\sin\angle FDG}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\angle FGD}{\sin\angle GFE}\tag{iv}$

Using sine law in $\Delta DEI$ you get $\dfrac{DI}{EI}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DEF}{\sin\angle EDG}$ and in $\Delta GEI$ you get $\dfrac{GI}{EI}=\dfrac{\sin\angle GEF}{\sin\angle EGD}$. Dividing the two you'll obtain: $\dfrac{DI}{GI}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DEF}{\sin\angle EDG}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\angle EGD}{\sin\angle GEF}\tag{v}$

Combining (iv) and (v): $\dfrac{DI}{GI}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DFE}{\sin\angle FDG}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\angle FGD}{\sin\angle GFE}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DEF}{\sin\angle EDG}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\angle EGD}{\sin\angle GEF}\tag{vi}$

Doing the same thing with $DB$ and $GB$ you will get $$\dfrac{DB}{GB}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DFE}{\sin\angle GFE}\dfrac{\sin\angle BGF}{\sin\angle BDF}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DEF}{\sin\angle GEF}\dfrac{\sin\angle BGE}{\sin\angle BDE}\tag{vii}$$

Dividing (vi) and (vii) you get:$$\dfrac{\sin\angle FGD}{\sin\angle FDG}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\angle BDF}{\sin\angle BGF}=\dfrac{\sin\angle DGE}{\sin\angle GDE}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\angle BDE}{\sin\angle BGE}\tag{viii}$$

Now due to the Property 1 on [this](http://www3.ul.ie/~rynnet/swconics/EP%27s.htm) link, $\angle FGD=\angle BGE, \angle GDE=\angle BDF,\angle DGE=\angle BGF$ and $\angle BDE=\angle FDG$. Making the necessary substitutions, relation (viii) becomes:$$\sin^2\angle BGE \cdot\sin^2\angle BDF=\sin^2\angle BDE \cdot\sin^2\angle BGF$$ $$\sin\angle BGE \cdot\sin\angle BDF=\sin\angle BDE \cdot\sin\angle BGF\tag{ix}$$

Combining (iii) and (ix): $DE\cdot FG=GE\cdot FD$

**NOTE:** Making use of the relations (vi),(vii) and (ix) it is easy to see that $\dfrac{DI}{GI}=\dfrac{DB}{GB}$. By the [Angle Bisector Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), this means that $\angle DBF = \angle GBF$ and similarly $\angle FAG = \angle EAG$.